# Import new c++ Workspace into eclipse and have eclpise recognize function relationships etc

Tags: c++, eclipse

This might have been answered already or be available in eclipse itself. I prefer to get a solution faster.

I have been given a whole c++ workspace and I need to understand the code. One thing that I find very useful in eclipse is that it automatically detects and links class instances to relevant header and code files inside the workspace. For example, if inside the code an instance of class XX is defined as XX a; I want to be able to right click on XX and choose open declaration and get to the class .hh and .cc file.  I have already imported this workspace into eclipse. But I don't see eclipse performing this linking that I am talking about.

Two questions:
1) Am I importing the workspace correctly and do I need to take a further step so eclipse would peform the linking?

2) If this goes back to incorrectly importing the workspace so the linking is done properly, what is the correct way of importing the workspace?

Comment: Have you tried re-building the index? Right-click on the project in question -> Index -> Rebuild

Comment: How did you import the project? I usually use "New > Makefile project with existing code" (assuming there is no existing eclipse project files .project and .cproject), Then it will do the indexing. Of course, the indexing is not guaranteed to find everything, but then you should at least get red marks under the words, and then you need to add include directories, defines, etc. to the project, so that eclipse can resolve all links.

Comment: I actually didn't use Makefile. I used the Import option under File to import a whole workspace, which has a few make files.

Comment: I also tried the right click option on one of the makefilesand it doesn't give me an index option